# Access remote resources with impersonated token

Tags: c, windows, security, winapi

I want to impersonation a user on a windows server (2012/2016/2019) in a domain environment.
This should happened by a administrator account with SE_DEBUG and SE_IMPERSONATE privileges.

```
GetAccessToken()
DuplicateTokenEx()
CreateProcessWithTokenW(token, LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY, L"c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe", NULL, 0, FALSE, NULL, &si, &pi)
```

Until now its working fine.

But i have to read a fileshare on another server in context of the impersonated user/token.
On localhost the created process have all permissions from the original user/process.
If try to access a fileshare or any other server on the Network this results in "Access Denied".

I found out that it is depending on the logon type if users credentials are available on the system which is needed to connect to another system. (double hop)
But also if the impersonated process is started from an interactive logon (tried RDP und runas.exe)there seems to be no rights on remote systems.
I checked the Logon Type of the token GetTokenInformation() to get session id and then call LsaGetLogonSessionData() to get field LogonType.
Where is the difference between this and get TokenOrigin Variable from GetTokenInformation?

Which configuration allows me to access remote share with the impersonated token?

Comment: I want to understand what you're doing. You're spinning up a cmd shell and then using that to access a remote share on a machine that's in the same domain? The account is a domain account?

Comment: @MichaelHoward-MSFT Yes a local administrator spinning up a cmd shell in context oh another logged in (via RDP) domain account and tries to access a fileshare on another server i the same domain. 
So yes it is a domain account which has privileges to access the fileshare.

Comment: Can you try a non-admin account that's a domain user?

Comment: do you mean a from a non-elevated token or ah real user (no admin on server)? where is the difference in impersonating admin or non-admin?

Comment: Do you use `LogonUser` to implement `GetAccessToken`? Check this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/b98771ea-a25a-4a73-81be-111f3d77d8ae/access-denied-after-impersonating-an-user?forum=windowscompatibility), `LogonUser` API will not give you an elevated token with interactive logon. In addition you could also use [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wnet/adding-a-network-connection) to add a Network Connection

Comment: No i dont use LogonUser. I use OpenProcess() and OpenProcessToken(). How can i check if the token is elevated and non restricted. I only checked TOKEN_ELEVATION from GetTokenInformation. Here i get a true. Are the another Flags in the Token which describes the network access?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, can you directly use this user to access the shared file through explore.exe? Does this user have permission to access the share?

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference in impersonating a admin vs non-admin, but a *LOCAL* admin does not necessarily have access to the another machine. A domain user does.

Comment: All involved Users are Domain Users and have Access to the another machine.